# References pertinent to a conjecture about the computability of classical mechanics?

Tags: logic, reference-request, computer-science, computability, classical-mechanics

I'm looking for any references for result relevant to the following conjecture:

Conjecture: For any computable Lagrangian $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{L}(t,{\bf q}, {\bf \dot{q}})$, then for any computable initial conditions ${\bf q}(0), {\bf \dot{q}}(0)$, ${\bf q}(t), {\bf \dot{q}}(t)$ are computable functions. Where computability is taken in the type-2 theory of effectivity sense as laid out by Weihrauch.

There is also the analogous conjecture for computable Hamiltonians and ${\bf q}, {\bf p}$.

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203608/is-the-universe-a-turing-machine) physics stack exchange post, a user claim without apparent evidence that "classical mechanics is known to be non-computable", though I'm not really sure what that is intended to mean, also he didn't give a reference (and I haven't been able to find one, he reference "rapidly accelerating computer" as part of the proof of this claim, though that doesn't give any useful results on a first search). Of course we need constraints on what kinds of Lagrangians/Hamiltonians/force laws we are working with, because if these are themselves noncomputable functions, there are certainly cases where the particle trajectories are noncomputable.

Any relevant papers would be much appreciated. Of course, counterexample would be good as well. It's worth noting the there is a [result](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81930022.pdf) by Pour-El and Richards that says the wave equation will time evolve "computable" initial  data to a "non-computable" state for a computable time value. This is using I believe a different notion of computability from Weihrauch and there is a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228725982_Is_wave_propagation_computable_or_can_wave_computers_beat_the_Turing_machine_Proc) by Weihrauch and Zhong that explain that the Pour-El/Richards result doesn't violate the physical Church-Turing thesis and that the solution is always computable in the sense laid out in the paper.

PS: If any references for the case that we are working with field Lagrangians/Hamiltonians are known, they are also welcome.

Note: I have looked at [Physics and Church–Turing Thesis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54820/physics-and-church-turing-thesis) on MO. I don't think anything there is useful to this problem.

Comment: "Rapidly accelerating computers" are discussed in various places, e.g. [here](http://www.cthisspace.com/ftl/macaw/dynamics.html) and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3tejKrkWkD8C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%22accelerating+computer%22+classical+mechanics&source=bl&ots=COur2F-rya&sig=ACfU3U0G9yPnZcBhnv8v7YuuMytiCQ97ug&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJw4aQqqzlAhUCQawKHUfsD58Q6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22accelerating%20computer%22%20classical%20mechanics&f=false), and (according to Stewart) is somewhat related to [Xia's construction](https://www.ams.org/notices/199505/saari-2.pdf) in classical mechanics.

Comment: Hmmm. I can't come up with a reason that this isn't allowed by Lagrangian mechanics, but I also don't see how one could possibly write equations which implement the proposal of a rapidly accelerating computer. Can this concept by made actual by writing down a (computable) Lagrangian which starts on (computable) initial date and performs the steps of a Turing machine with increasing rate s.t. infinite steps happen in finite time, ultimately flipping some "switch" giving an uncomputable output? There seems no way to actualize this, and so doesn't necessarily contradict my conjecture.

Comment: I don't know nearly enough to actually give an answer - I just wanted to give citations for the specific thing mentioned in the referenced answer.